# Proof by induction when numbers are to powers

Tags: induction

Prove by mathematical induction:
$$
2^n+3^n < 5^n$$

Comment: For exactly which values of $n$ are we proving this? Ideally, you should also share your own thoughts and ideas on the problem.

Answer (score 11):

The given inequality is valid for $n=2$. Assume that it is valid for some $n$, $n\ge 2$. Then for $n+1$ we have

$$5^{n+1}=5\times 5^n>5(2^n+3^n)>2\times 2^n+3\times 3^n=2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}$$
and we get the result.

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial theorem, $5^n=(2+3)^n=2^n+\cdots+3^n > 2^n+3^n$, because all missing terms are positive. Note that you need $n\ge2$ to have any missing terms.

Comment: Induction appears in the binomial theorem...

Answer (score 0):

Show $2^2+3^2<5^2$

Assume $2^n+3^n<5^n$

Prove $2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}<5^{n+1}$:

- $2^{n+1}+3^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n+3\cdot3^n$
- $2\cdot2^n+3\cdot3^n<3\cdot2^n+3\cdot3^n$
- $3\cdot2^n+3\cdot3^n=3\cdot(2^n+3^n)$
- $3\cdot(2^n+3^n)<3\cdot5^n$ `assumption used here`
- $3\cdot5^n<5\cdot5^n$
- $5\cdot5^n=5^{n+1}$

Answer (score 0):

This is a proof without induction:
Lets define two continuous functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}^+_0\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f(x)=\Big(\dfrac{2}{5}\Big)^x$$ and $$g(x)=1-\Big(\dfrac{3}{5}\Big)^x$$ Note that $f(0)=1$ and $g(0)=0.$
Also $f$ is strictly decreasing and $g$ is strictly increasing.
Therefore they can have at most one intersection point. They intersect for $x=1$: $f(1)=\dfrac 2 5 = g(1)$. So, in particular, $g(n) > f(n)$ for all $n \geq 2$. That is to say $1-3^n/5^n > 2^n/5^n$ or $5^n > 2^n + 3^n$ for all $n \geq 2$.

Answer (score -1):

since we have $$\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n<1$$
it is clear for all $n>1$.

Comment: This is *not* clear for *all* $n$

Comment: Inequality breaks for n = 1.

Comment: Where's the "proof by induction"?

Comment: @barakmanos: if you will, you can prove by induction that each of those fractions is less than $\frac12$

Comment: @Ilya: if we're talking about integral $n$.